# Apply a List of Arguments to a List of Functions

Tags: list-manipulation

Happy new year, everyone! I hope this is a good one.

The title doesn't really express well what I want to do, however, please see further explenation below.

Say, I have a list of functions `flist` - `{f,g,h}` where function `f` takes three arguments; function `g` takes six arguments; and function `h` takes four arguments. Furthermore, I have an argument list `alist` with randomly generated numbers which will serve as an input to the above functions.

How could I apply argument list `alist` to `flist` in such a way where each function in `flist` would take appropriate subset of elements from `alist`; whilst ensuring functions in `flist` do not share elements  from `alist`.

**Example**

```
flist = {f,g,h};
alist = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

~magic~ 

f[1,2,3]
g[4,5,6,7,8,9]
h[10,11,12,13]
```

I know I could do something like

```
f @@ alist[[;;3]]
g @@ alist[[4;;9]]
h @@ alist[[10;;13]]
```

This said, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. A more ~lazy~ approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 MapThread[Apply] @ {flist, TakeList[alist, {3, 6, 4}]}
```

> f[1, 2, 3], g[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], h[10, 11, 12, 13]}

Also

```
MapThread[# @@ #2 &] @ {flist, TakeList[alist, {3, 6, 4}]}
```

> {f[1, 2, 3], g[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], h[10, 11, 12, 13]}

**Update:** If `TakeList` is not available in your version, you can use `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` or `FoldPairList` + `TakeDrop`:

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[alist, {3, 6, 4}] == 
 FoldPairList[TakeDrop, alist, {3, 6, 4}] == 
  TakeList[alist, {3, 6, 4}]
```

> True

Comment: how would you implement above in Mathematica version 11.0.1.0? Unfortunately, I do not have `TakeList` function available :s

Comment: @e.doroskevic, please see the update.